# Intuition for Jensen inequality.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that for $\varphi$ convex, $$\varphi\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx\right)\leq \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b\varphi(f(x))dx,$$
I also know how to prove it, but I don't understand the intuition behind. Any idea ?

Comment: Convex functions lie above their graphs. So you can think of $\phi$ as the supremum of a family of linear functions. The supremum of family of integrals will clear be less than the integral of supremum of the functions that generates those integrals.

Comment: The result is very intuitive. You know that every convex function is such that $f( (1-\lambda)x+\lambda y) \leq f(\lambda x) + f((1-\lambda)y)$ with $\lambda,x,y$ as usual. Now think of $\lambda \mapsto (1-\lambda)x+\lambda y$. You will notice that this affine function is not really different from $f \mapsto \int_a^b f\,dx$, thinking $a,b$ as replacements for $x,y$.

Comment: You might be interested in the graphical "proof" here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality. It simply follows from the convexity of $\phi$ when you consider the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that for a convex function $\phi$ we have
$\phi(c_1 x_1 + \cdots + c_n x_n) \leq c_1 \phi(x_1) + \cdots + c_n \phi(x_n)$ when the weights are nonnegative and sum to $1$.

Just approximate the integral on the left by a Riemann sum and apply this inequality. "In the limit" we obtain your inequality.

Here's a bit more detail.  Partition $[a,b]$ as $a = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_N = b$ and select numbers $\xi_i \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$ for $i = 0,\ldots,N-1$.  Let $\Delta x_i = x_{i+1} - x_i$ (for $i = 0,\ldots,N-1$).  Then
\begin{align*}
\phi\left(\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \right) & 
\approx \phi\left(\frac{1}{b-a} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} f(\xi_i) \Delta x_i \right) \\
&\leq \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{\Delta x_i}{b-a} \phi(f(\xi_i)) \\
&\approx \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b \phi(f(x)) \, dx.
\end{align*}
The inequality in line 2 follows because $\phi$ is convex and the "weights" $\Delta x_i/(b-a)$ are nonnegative and sum to $1$.

Answer (score 3):

- $\displaystyle\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d x$ is the *mean value* of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$,
- Suppose $\varphi(x)\ge 0$ on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b\varphi(x)\,\mathrm dx=1$.

$\qquad\displaystyle  \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b\varphi(f(x))\,\mathrm dx$ is the *weighted mean* of $f$ on  $[a,b]$ (for the weight function $f$).

*Jensen's inequality* can be interpreted as saying that, for a convex weight function $\varphi$, the image of the mean of a function $f\,$ by $\varphi$ is no more than the  $\varphi$-weighted mean of $f$.